# How to use crypto (methods: randomBytes(), createCipheriv(), createDecipheriv()) or similar approach in Angular 12?

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am using crypto (methods: randomBytes(), createCipheriv(), createDecipheriv()) in node.js for encryption and decryption of user credentials, which works fine.
On the other hand, I have to use the same approach to getting the exact result of encryption and decryption in Angular. As it's confirmed that crypto is not working in Angular. I would like to know any relative way to achieve the require result.

Please, guide me if someone have relative knowledge.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Web Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) though it isn't as mature as the crypto module from node.js.

There are other 3rd partly libs too like [webcrypto](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto)

Comment: Shivam, there is no support of encrypt/ decrypt for aes-cbc in webcrypto. I am looking to use ass-256-cbc.